# Coping value from a dynamic intersection of column and row

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup, vlookup

Using the function `LOOKUP` and *Conditional Formatting* in excel I did the large table below. The cell highlighted in red is the result of the intersection between the column labeled **7** and the row labeled **20**. Just as a additional information, the column and row to be intersected depend on values in the small table (values 7 and 20).

What I need to do is link the value (27) from the highlighted cell with a formula in other cell. Let's say  a multiplication with each value in the third column in the small table. The formula should be able to follow the column-row intersection when this change as a result of changes in the ***sum*** of the small table (values 7 and 20 will change). Alternatively, the value in the red cell can be replicated in other cell and from there the multiplication can be done. I have tried to do it with no success using `LOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX`, `MATCH`; therefore, any help will be much appreciated.

Tables:

[image: Large table]

[image: Small table]

Values in case you need them to test your suggestion.

Small table:

```
1   1   3
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   1   3
5   1   3
6   1   3
7   1   3
8   0   0
sum 7   20
```

Large table:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
2   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
3   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
4   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
5   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
6   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
7   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
8   15  20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
9   5   20  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
10  5   10  25  28  31  33  34  35  36
11  5   10  15  28  31  33  34  35  36
12  0   10  15  18  31  33  34  35  36
13  0   0   15  18  23  33  34  35  36
14  0   0   5   18  23  30  34  35  36
15  0   0   5   8   23  30  28  31  36
16  0   0   0   8   15  30  28  31  36
17  0   0   0   0   15  22  28  31  32
18  0   0   0   0   7   22  22  31  32
19  0   0   0   0   7   22  22  27  32
20  0   0   0   0   0   16  16  27  27
21  0   0   0   0   0   16  16  21  27
22  0   0   0   0   0   8   10  21  21
23  0   0   0   0   0   8   10  15  21
24  0   0   0   0   0   0   4   9   15
```

Comment: Did you try a [two-dimensional Index/Match](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275170)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cell with highlighting is in `I22` and that the summing cells in the smaller array are [named](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx) `Csum` and `Nsum`, please try:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(CHAR(cSUM+66)&":"&CHAR(cSUM+66)),Nsum+2)
```

The basic structure of which is [`=INDEX`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) in the Syntax #1 version described there. However, rather than specifying the array and then choosing the column_number I chose to leave off the optional column number parameter and define the array as the relevant column.

In outline:

```
=INDEX(first_parameter, second_parameter)
```

where the second parameter is the row number derived from the sum of **N<sup>o</sup> Quota** offset by `2` for the two header rows in the larger array.

The first parameter is constructed within [=INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx):

```
=CHAR(cSUM+66)
```

twice with the [ampersand concatenation operator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx):

```
&":"&
```

to insert a colon between the two.

Since the seventh column in the large array has been taken to be ColumnI and [=CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/char.php) with a value of 73 returns I the required column number character value is 66 more than the sum of **Contributing**.

The above approach would however fail is the larger array extends beyond ColumnZ. So an alternative would be to specify the body (B3:J26 based on the above assumption) of the large array (say as a named range of `Larray`) and uses this outline:

```
=INDEX(Larray, second_parameter, third_parameter)
```

in this way:

```
=INDEX(Larray,Nsum,Csum)
```